# Using LaTeX to draft a technical book

Tags: publishing

Having drafted a technical book manuscript; replete with equations, tables, and graphics, using LaTeX; will "vanity" presses accept this as input, or do they prefer other formats or some entirely different approach?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I suppose that if a publisher merely requires the manuscript to be in a "camera-ready" file format, e.g., pdf, they may not care how the pdf file was created. However, if a publisher has additional requirements, e.g. searchability using unicode-encoded characters as inputs, or accessibility requirements, you may need to tweak your document's properties. Best to ask each publisher directly...

Comment: This is probably too vague a question to be answered on the site. If a press is happy with PDF then they using LaTeX is not a problem. If they require tagged accessible PDF, then this is a yet to be seamlessly solved problem, although progress is being made.  If they have a work flow that builds multiple formats like epub from your source, they will be less likely to like LaTeX. But I don't think this is something that we can answer here.